# how to add onsubmit in scala form tag

Tags: forms, scala, playframework, onsubmit

I am new to scala and need to make a small change in the form tag. Currently the form tag in my html page is written like

```
@form(routes.LoginController.loginAuthenticate) {
```

I need to add onsubmit property in this form tag. I tried like

```
@form(routes.LoginController.loginAuthenticate, 'onSubmit' => 'validate()') {
```

but it is giving error.

Please suggest how can i add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *Play Twirl* templates expects after an `@` *Scala* code, **not** *Javascript*.

So `'onSubmit' => 'validate()'` is not valid.

It must be `'onSubmit -> "validate()"`

Be aware with **Scala 2.13** `'onSubmit` is deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

You should look at [the method definition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.1/api/scala/views/html/helper/form$.html). `apply` method takes `action: Call` and `args: (Symbol, String)*`.

```scala
def apply(action: Call, args: (Symbol, String)*)(body: ⇒ Html): Appendable
```

Your code should be like this

```scala
@form(routes.LoginController.loginAuthenticate, 'onSubmit -> "validate()") {
```

- Tuple `A -> B == (A, B)`
- Symbol `'s == Symbol("s")`
- String `"string"`
- Character `'c'`
- `=>` is for function